# Automated Teller machine detecting fake bank notes

Tags: design

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_teller_machine

Do ATM's detect fake bank notes and not accept / receive from customers giving them a "Fake notes detected" message on the screen?

Comment: The answer depends on which make and model of ATM machine? I suggest that this is a poor question.

Comment: The design tag is not appropriate here - you’ll see the help text shows that should be used for questions about the process of design itself, not about the design of specific objects.

Answer (score 3):

**Characteristics of a US Bill**

[image]

**Ultraviolet (UV) Detection**

Using of vertical florescent stripe that is undetectable to the naked eye, but glows brightly when exposed under UV light. Ultraviolet is the single most common method of counterfeit bill detection used in money counting machines due to its simplicity, affordability and relative effectiveness

**Magnetic (MG) Detection**

Use of magnetic inks in their paper currency is another method. Money counting machines equipped with MG detection scan each bill for the magnetic properties in the traces of iron particles in the ink. As with UV, MG detection is relatively effective

**Infrared (IR) Detection**

Infrared detection involves the use of IR inks which are currently extremely difficult if not impossible for counterfeiters to replicate. That is, currently currencies may be printed with IR inks that either reflect or absorb infrared light. Money counting machines with infrared technology use sensors that detect the presence of both types of IR inks, allowing them to identify legitimate currency by nation and denomination.

Some to other currency security technologies include color image sensing (CIS), infrared thickness (IR-T), metal thread coding (MT), watermarks, and paper composition.

---

**References:**

- [How Money Counting Machines Detect Counterfeit Bills – An Overview](https://carnation-inc.com/pages/how-money-counting-machines-detect-counterfeit-bills-an-overview#:%7E:text=Infrared%20(IR)%20Detection&text=Currencies%20may%20be%20printed%20with,And%20weed%20out%20the%20fakes.)
- [How to Identify Counterfeit Bills?](https://www.itestcash.com/blogs/news/how-to-identify-counterfeit-bills)

Comment: Paper? Most notes seem to be some sort of « plastic » now...

Comment: @SolarMike depends on the currency, developed countries plastic yes, some parts of the world they still use the good paper based currency.

Comment: “good” as in easy to counterfeit...

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=bank+notes+in+countries&client=ms-android-lava&prmd=inv&sxsrf=ALeKk02qGxIKaewwAxjtYUTY6tqlt4KI1w:1596396601897&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjWroHjoP3qAhVOeH0KHQMBAvMQ_AUoAXoECA4QAQ&biw=360&bih=592  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_central_banks 
ATM detecting and not accepting fake notes from customers for different countries have to be customised in terms of hardware and software manufacturing for achieving this feature? The ATM manufacturers viz Diebold, NCR, Wincor etc can achieve this feature as per Central Bank needs?

Comment: @PrashantAkerkar, What is purpose of the comment? Are asking a question. Also this information might be good to added to the body of the question.

Comment: Thanks Mahendra. I mean customisation of the ATM hardware & software to add this feature as per respective central bank of the country needs (If required)  is the solution?

Comment: I feel this is possible with programming. A system alert notification (email, sms) message is send to the respective bank from the ATM when Bank notes are detected as Fake/counterfeit.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=scanner+scanning+paper+stacks&oq=&aqs=chrome.0.35i39l4j69i176.-1j0j7&client=ms-android-lava&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8 https://www.google.com/search?q=scanner+scanning+paper+stacks&client=ms-android-lava&prmd=sivn&sxsrf=ALeKk00ZvlaOlWG3l3Pv3-WSQzww2ok7Vg:1596440217297&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiIiLqgw_7qAhU4zDgGHXqhAv0Q_AUoAnoECA8QAg&cshid=1596440282014&biw=360&bih=592&dpr=2 Bank notes enclosed in Paper envelope could be a limitation for ATM scanner hardware detecting fake bank note/s?

Comment: @PrashantAkerkar, I suggest adding this information to the body of the question. You can use the  [Edit](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/36961/automated-teller-machine-detecting-fake-bank-notes/36962?noredirect=1#comment66070_36962) to update the body of the question

Comment: Thanks Mahendra. https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/bps51535 The ATM can be interfaced with the  HP scanner device internally with the software for scanning bank notes stack?

Comment: https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FhIV4w29H8w4%2Fhqdefault.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DhIV4w29H8w4&tbnid=TAfHfp-Ofa9oWM&vet=12ahUKEwii_e2znv_qAhX9DbcAHTypCt8QMygMegUIARDjAQ..i&docid=puhXa3cZVBfTjM&w=480&h=360&q=hp%20network%20scanjet%20500&client=ms-android-lava&ved=2ahUKEwii_e2znv_qAhX9DbcAHTypCt8QMygMegUIARDjAQ

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=hp+network+scanjet+500&client=ms-android-lava&prmd=sivn&sxsrf=ALeKk00yZimq6kFhRPSMZ8pFJuzSRipMUg:1596465297009&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiznbLXoP_qAhWvzjgGHf4AA5sQ_AUoAnoECA8QAg&biw=360&bih=592

Comment: Reference : https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&sxsrf=ALeKk01hB7gnE61IFalsEm4wqjL6VEDl1g%3A1596465682288&source=hp&ei=EiIoX-_cD_6N4-EPnvWmoAE&q=+counterfeit+banknotes+detection+machine&oq=+counterfeit+banknotes+detection+machine&gs_lcp=ChJtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1pbWcQAzoHCCMQ6gIQJzoECCMQJzoICAAQsQMQgwE6BQgAELEDOgQIABADOgIIADoGCAAQCBAeOgQIABANOggIABANEAUQHjoFCAAQzQI6CAgAEAgQDRAeOgQIABAeOgQIABAYOgQIHhAKOgQIIRAKUKUWWJWbAmD1ogJoAXAAeAGAAYwFiAHWR5IBCjAuNTMuNC0yLjGYAQCgAQGwAQU&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-img

Comment: Reference : Ultraviolet scanner. https://www.google.com/search?q=ultraviolet+scanner&client=ms-android-lava&prmd=isvn&sxsrf=ALeKk03TVsmCB0_iSYv7Y8W4jSbbelTigw:1596482035270&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjIvuiE3__qAhUHlEsFHQ4ZCWUQ_AUoAXoECA0QAQ&biw=360&bih=592&dpr=2

Comment: @PrashantAkerkar, What is the purpose to adding all these links under comment? It will serve best if you include these links in the body of the question.

Comment: Thanks. https://www.google.com/search?q=ultraviolet+counterfeit+detection+scanner&prmd=isnv&sxsrf=ALeKk032jTWQmIAUDLTlFVCcdOyTHLoUZg:1596518249032&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiBpvH45YDrAhWOyzgGHVrYCSwQ_AUoAXoECA0QAQ&biw=360&bih=592 ATM interfaced with Ultraviolet counterfeit detection scanner device.

Comment: @PrashantAkerkar, I don't I understand what you are doing? Please stop spamming. Take the time to learn features of this forum.