# Multicurrency Ultraviolet counterfeit scanner detection machine

Tags: electrical-engineering, embedded-systems

https://www.google.com/search?q=ultraviolet+counterfeit+detection+scanner&client=ms-android-lava&prmd=sinv&sxsrf=ALeKk00_7L1PhL1uvSYN10i3xef6-Oq4sQ:1597382808532&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUnP3W-pnrAhXz7HMBHSHNAU0Q_AUoAnoECA4QAg&biw=360&bih=592

Is it technically feasible to design & manufacture Multicurrency Ultraviolet counterfeit detection scanner machine by device programming?

By selecting and inputting the specific currency on the Scanner front panel button and then feeding the desired currency note/s in the scanner device for counterfeit detection.

Select Currency Mode : USD, Euros, GBP, Antillean Guilder, INR, Francs, Yen ....

Can this be classified as a Interesting Research and Development Fintech Domain product reengineering?

Comment: Not sure which part of the technology you are looking for, but some useful info may be found here : https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/36962/10902

Comment: Thanks Mike. I mean the Multicurrency Ultraviolet counterfeit detection scanner can detect different currency notes with programming for checking fake notes. For example : USD, Euros, GBP, INR, Canadian dollars etc. The product can accept currencies of different countries. Is this technically feasible to implement this product functionality?. The product is modified (Hardware + Software) to have this feature added.

Answer (score 1):

Not all currencies have ultraviolet features. Of those that do, the features vary.

Any ultraviolet features are determined by the issuing authority and are also influenced by the material the banknotes are made from: [cotton/rag paper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotton_paper) (typical of US banknotes and older styled banknotes) or [polymer](http://Polymer%20banknote) (typical of Australian banknotes).

If one knew all the ultraviolet features of all the banknotes in the world and had a computerized system that could recognize all banknotes from the world and all their ultraviolet features and one was prepared to keep the system updated with changes to banknotes and their security features one could make a device.

The key aspect of ultraviolet currency scanners is that forged banknotes generally do not include the ultraviolet security features of valid banknotes.

If someone knows that a particular currency has ultraviolet security features and a banknote placed under ultraviolet let does not glow, as expected, the banknote can be determined to be a forgery.

Multi currency ultraviolet detectors are a marketing gimmick.

Comment: Thanks Fred. Is this product more useful for Foreign exchange banks and Financial institutions dealing in currencies exchange as per everyday currency exchange rates? https://www.google.com/search?q=currencies+in+the+world&oq=Currencies+in+the&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l3.6453j0j7&client=ms-android-lava&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8 As there are many currencies in the world, could this be a challenging part for designing and manufacturing for this product?

Comment: https://www.travelex.com/currency/current-world-currencies There are total 180 current currencies in the world.

Comment: Reference : https://www.moneypoint.ie/ie/latest-news/using-uv-lights-for-counterfeit-detection/ https://youtu.be/_RNtVjOdVMc